# jquery.click(function) wordpress widget

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

when i use this function in my header, it works fine but when i use it in a widget nothing happens

```
$("#myID").click(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    console.log(name +" "+ phone); 
    if(name.length > 1 && phone.length > 7){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'my_url',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'name': name,
        'number': phone},
        success: function(data){
        $(".header-bg-title").html('thanks');
        $("span.white").hide();
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert('error'); 
        }
    });
    } else {
        $("p#onerror").html('write your name & number');
    }

});
```

html

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h2>text</h2>
<p id="onerror">My text</p>
<p><input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" /></p>
<p><input id="phone" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Phone" /></p>
<p><button id="myID" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" type="button">Send</button></p>
</div>
```

anyone who got a suggestion?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem or do you have a site for us to test?

Comment: **nothing happens** is very vague, please contribute what you've looked at before and provide other valuable information so we more easily can build up a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: _when i use it in a widget_, are you including this widget by Ajax?

Comment: try and attach the event to the body instead? `$('body').on('click', '#myID', function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware .click will attach to the item when it is executed, if the item is not there, in the case of a widget it will not be attached. I could be wrong on that, try this and see if it works.

```
$('body').on('click', '#myID', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: It was a good start, Gavin, now reacts button when I press it, but $('name').val() & $('phone').val() is empty in the log

Comment: Try to avoid using ID's for widgets as they can be duplicated and then lead to script failures, if you use class' or data attributes to identify elements you can then use something like `$('[data-input="name"]', this).val();` in the widget... Not sure if that will solve your issue though, would need to see more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery function, not $.

Your code would be this:

```
jQuery("#myID").click(function(){
    var name = jQuery("#name").val();
    var phone = jQuery("#phone").val();
    console.log(name +" "+ phone); 
    if(name.length > 1 && phone.length > 7){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'my_url',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'name': name,
            'number': phone},
            success: function(data){
                jQuery(".header-bg-title").html('thanks');
                jQuery("span.white").hide();
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert('error'); 
            }
        });
    } else {
        jQuery("p#onerror").html('write your name & number');
    }
});
```

or you can wrap your code in an IIFE receiving jQuery in your $

```
(function($) {
// your code here
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you currently have a function like this

```
$(document)ready(function(){
  $("#myID").click(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    console.log(name +" "+ phone); 
    if(name.length > 1 && phone.length > 7){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'my_url',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'name': name,
        'number': phone},
        success: function(data){
        $(".header-bg-title").html('thanks');
        $("span.white").hide();
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert('error'); 
        }
    });
    } else {
        $("p#onerror").html('write your name & number');
    }
  });
}
```

If so it should be as easy as changing the $(document)ready(function(){ to jQuery(document).ready(function($)  and keeping the rest the same.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
 $("#myID").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        console.log(name +" "+ phone); 
        if(name.length > 1 && phone.length > 7){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'my_url',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'name': name,
            'number': phone},
            success: function(data){
            $(".header-bg-title").html('thanks');
            $("span.white").hide();
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert('error'); 
            }
        });
        } else {
            $("p#onerror").html('write your name & number');
        }
      });
}
```

This solution allows you to keep using $('#idofitem')